# Nativescript ng g '@schematics/angular/utility/config' error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I got past the `'@schematics/angular/utility/parse-name'` error by following the recommended steps. But now I get this error:

> [error] Error: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
> Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@nativescript\schematics\src\angular-project-parser.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@nativescript\schematics\src\generate\component\index.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> - C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
>   at Object. (C:\Users\user\folder\ns-ng-course\node_modules@nativescript\schematics\src\angular-project-parser.js:7:18)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

I have installed angular cli both globally and in the work folder, I have deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock` and reinstalled, nothing changed.
This is my `package.json`:

```
     "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/core": "~7.1.0",
        "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^11.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
        "@schematics/angular": "^11.2.1",
        "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
        "@nativescript/schematics": "^11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
        "@nativescript/webpack": "~4.0.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.1",
        "eslint": "^7.20.0",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "typescript": "~4.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945814/nativescript-angular-project-error-an-unhandled-exception-occurred-cannot-fi

Comment: @TianNa ok, but my title says that I get a /config error. The first line of my question says that I have solved the 'parse-name' problem. The title of the question in your link is about the 'parse-name' problem...